# Is there a way to automate Google Slides Template customization?

Tags: automation, google-docs, build-automation, google-slides

I have a document used for presentations. Every time I deliver a service to this client there are specific images (ex: logos), on specific slides, I need to adapt for each client.

Is there a way to automate this process? 
Ideally would be great if it allowed me to have a folder with the images, even if the images need to have a specific name, and run the script that would update them.

Although it's not a complicated task to do manually, from my estimates this will save me around 100h in 1 year.